# "It doesn't fly, but hop(s)"

Tags: verbs, negation

Quick question: "It does not fly, but hop" or "It does not fly, but hops". I'm certain, it is the first one, my teacher claims, the second one is correct. Which one is correct and why?

Comment: Your teacher is overly close-minded. Both versions are perfectly grammatical (and *idiomatic*, imho). It just depends on whether we assume ***but [verb]*** is shorthand for *but it **does hop*** or *but it **hops***. You pays your money and you takes your choice, as they say. A *stylistic* choice.

Comment: Thanks, can you reference any sources?

Comment: This is your source. It's called ELU. Use it as your reference.

Comment: To add further confusion, though, personally I wouldn't use either version. I'd say "It doesn't fly but it hops". With a second *it*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Strange really. In the example *hops* sounds the more natural. But If you say *It does not so much fly as hop*, then I prefer *hop* to *hops*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt This is a precedence problem whose ambiguity derives from how negated English auxiliaries function as “fused” negated verbs in their own right: *He doesn’t eat* inverts to *Doesn’t he eat?* not to *Does ⚹not he eat?*. So the compound predicate governed by a shared singular subject appears to be a fused *doesn’t fly* as one verb and *hop* as the other; the auxiliary doesn’t distribute and so the number is wrong for *hop*, since it no longer matches singular *it*. It’s **IT (DOES NOT) VERB1 (BUT) VERB2.**

Comment: @WS2: I'd guess the inflected version of "verb2" form is likely to be more common in contexts featuring contraction - *It doesn't [verb1] but [verb2]*, because the contraction "de-emphasises" the **DO** component. This makes it a less obvious candidate for "deletion" in the second clause. But my choice would depend on the *full* context, and I don't think it's all that meaningful to express a "preference" for either version without that full context.

Comment: I might argue for a slight distinction in meaning, with a slight change in how but is used. *But hop* could be read as hopping is the only kind of flying it does, a la I don't eat meat but steak.

Comment: @Unrelated: I don't deny there might be structurally similar utterances where ***but*** can reasonably be used in a negating assertion with the meaning ***except***. But I don't find your example idiomatic - I'd expect *I eat **no** meat **but** steak* there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I might give you that. First thing to come to mind. Also not helpful because steak is a noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also worth adding to what FumbleFingers has just said that the reason your teacher does not like the first option (if indeed it is an option!) is probably due to how it sounds with regards conventions of pluralisation.  Just think about this sentence, "They do not fly, but hop".  It sounds correct because the 'hop' tells the reader that the subject of the sentence is a group of things and not just one thing.  It is the same principle as the difference between "She is an engineer and loves her job" and "She is an engineer and love her job".  You probably wouldn't want to argue that 'love her job' is shorthand for 'she does love her job'; it does not *sound* correct.

There's also something to be said here for emphasis.  By adding the proposed shorthand 'but it does hop', it seems like the author is making the point that the object (an animal I presume) is not all that disadvantaged in its mobility.  By removing the 'does' the emphasis is no longer present.  This is not taken care of with the replacement of 'hops' but the point I'm making is that if you are wanting to emphasise then it makes sense to use 'does' and not 'hop' unaccompanied by its emphasising partner.

Whilst I agree with FumbleFingers that it is overly close-minded to restrict language in this way, I assume that you are wanting to understand conventions and it is not, as far as I know, conventional to say that 'but hop' is shorthand for 'but it does hop'.  I believe your teacher is referring to this distinction.  Generally, 'shorthands' have to be learnt through experience and cannot be assumed logically.

Comment: “She is an engineer and love her job” is an entirely different construction. You can infer implicit, _repeated_ auxiliaries, but not ones that have not already appeared in the sentence, and there is no ‘does’ in “She is an engineer”. You could say “She is an engineer and fond of her job” and then infer an implicit ‘is’. A more natural-sounding example that parallels the one in the question could be “He didn't shoot, but stab, his wife”. As WS2 mentions, if you add “so much… as”, the preference for infinitives grows: “He didn't so much dance as hop around aimlessly”.

Comment: The sentence could be "She does not like art but love engineering" and my argument would continue to stand. To be clear, my point was simply adding to @FumbleFingers's, which is to say that it is a matter of convention whether or not to imply the missing verb. For example, convention tells us that "It does not fly but it hops more than I" is fine but it should contain an additional 'do'.  It could just as easily be any verb for it to be grammatically correct but we'd have to specify which one for it to feel right, precisely because we expect 'do'.

Answer (score -2):

The second one is correct.

The reason is with subject-verb agreement.  The subject and verb must agree in number, tense, and .

The subject is "it", which is singular.  Hop is the plural form, while hops is singular.

While there are many exceptions, plural verbs do not have an "s" ending "and adding an s to a verb makes the verb singular.

"Watching the bunnies hop, the child hops also."

[Subject-verb agreement in the Online Writing Support section of Towson University](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/moduleSVAGR.htm)

Comment: This has nothing to do with agreement. “It doesn't fly but hop” has one finite verb (_does_) and two infinitives (_fly_ and _hop_); while “It doesn't fly but hops” has two finite verbs (_does_ and _hops_) and one infinitive (_fly_). They're simply different grammatical constructions, both valid, and both adhering to subject-verb agreement as they should.