# Trying to find a grammar rule that explains heavy use of ‘but’ instead of ‘that doesn’t’ in older English

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, negation

I have seen quite a few sentences that look like this in 18th and 19th century literature:

> There was hardly a lawyer of repute **but took up** the question, and had an opinion as to Lizzie’s right to the necklace.
>
> ― Anthony Trollope, *The Eustace Diamonds* (1871)

> And as for canes, hardly a man **but has** a half-dozen or more of all styles, colors, and weights.
>
> ― Mark Sibley Severance, *Hammersmith: His Harvard Days* (1878)

> And after this matter it is said we come to the abstract idea
> of man, or, if you please, humanity, or human nature; wherein
> it is true there is included colour, because there is no man
> **but has** some colour, but then it can be neither white, nor
> black, nor any particular colour, because there is no one
> particular colour wherein all men partake.
>
> ― George Berkeley, *The Principles of Human Knowledge* (1710)

These *but*s are very akin to *that doesn’t* or *doesn’t have*. (Note that in the first sentence, Trollope means that reputable lawyers ᴅɪᴅ take up the question, as revealed by context, since he goes on to list a couple of solicitors and attorneys with opinions.)

Then there are a few easier explained that use *but* strictly instead of *that*:

> I thank your Lordship for your invitation to Chilbolton,
> but I fear it is impracticable this year, It is not impossible
> **but** that next year I may have the honour of waiting on your
> Lordship at Sᵗ. Asaph, If I go to Ireland I certainly will go
> that way.
>
> ― Sir Joshua Reynolds, Letter LXXVII¹ (1784)

But using that rule on Trollope’s sentence would turn the sentence on its head completely.

I would like to learn more about the former usage, and what kind of rules explain it.

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80853), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9235), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/69212), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/355092).

Comment: This has to do with the negative _hardly_, in whose scope _but_ has a special sense and forms an idiom.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of what I call the *nobbut* construction. All of the examples cited involve negatives (*hardly, not, no*) which invoke the special "except" meaning of *but* in their scope. This is quite common outside of literature, though usually not to this length.

- *No one but Harry would have suggested that.*
- *He wants nothing but the best.*

Compare these with ungrammatical non-negatives:

- **Someone but Harry would have suggested that*
- **He wants something but the best*

Since nobbut constructions are used to single out something, they're available for specialized [uses like clefts](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Nobbut.pdf).

- *Nothing remains but to thank you for your attention.*

To repeat: this has nothing to do with *that,* or relative clauses; it has to do with [negative polarity](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20negative%20polarity).

Comment: No one but you would come up with such a "fancy like" word as nobbut. I look forward to not having to italicize it. [A joke I hope everyone realizes, But true.]

Comment: I don't understand. How does `Hardly a lawyer except took up the question` make sense?

Comment: The original sentence was an existential: _There was hardly a lawyer but took up the question_. It meant that there were practically no lawyers, except the ones who took up the question.

Answer (score 2):

A famous sentence having this rather archaic *but* is:

> *It never rains but it pours.*

And I've always thought that this *but* means "unless":

> *It never rains unless it pours.*

Although the former is sort of a set phrase and thus much more productive, we do have [some attested examples of the latter in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20never%20rains%20unless%20it%20pours%22&rlz=1C1NHXL_koKR936KR936&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT7M6Nk-z0AhVDIaYKHSRLBusQpwV6BAgBEC0&biw=1280&bih=609&dpr=1.5):

Considering that *but* and *except* are frequently treated as synonyms, and more importantly that [*except* has an archaic meaning of "unless"](https://www.lexico.com/definition/except) (as in *She never offered advice, except it were asked of her.*), it's not surprising at all that the archaic *but* also has the meaning of 'unless'.

Admittedly, though, the syntactic behavior of this archaic *but* is not as clear-cut as I'd hope it to be, so you can't always replace the *but* with *unless* and make the sentence flawless in Present-day English. But you get the point.

Comment: 'Unless' is usually used with enabling conditions. _It never rains unless there are clouds in the sky_.  On the other hand, _It never rains but [what] it pours_. means 'It never just rains slightly; if it rains at all, there's a real downpour.' Accompanying qualifications.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why did you put _what_ in there?

Comment: [It's a rather old variant, as in the Gershwin song](https://sonichits.com/video/Judy_Garland/It_Never_Rains%2C_But_What_It_Pours). + [Dayton Revue, 1941](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1112&dat=19410904&id=EFNlAAAAIBAJ&sjid=0ZMNAAAAIBAJ&pg=914,4823543). Also, [Manchester Evening News, as late as 2005](https://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/news/local-news/dont-know-why-theres-no-sun-1173646).

Comment: So what does `It never rains but it pours` mean?

Comment: I mean, it looks like the most ordinary use of `but` imaginable. I don't see how it relates to my question. I have no idea why you thought it meant `unless`.

Comment: @Yeats If that's "the most ordinary use of _but_ imaginable", it shouldn't make any sense. I wonder how you'd understand the proverb. // If you have no idea why it means "unless", then you shouldn't have any idea why those cited Google Books examples used "unless" instead of "but".

Comment: @JK2 To me it means, "When it rains it pours". If I were gluttonous, I could say "I don't eat food, I devour it" or "I don't eat but I devour".

Comment: The cited sources are modern and may have misunderstood/misremembered the proverb. You said yourself it didn't mean `unless` so I don't really understand your post at all. You never say what it does mean!

Comment: @Yeats But your own examples could be rephrased with "unless": _I don't eat unless I devour_.

Comment: @JK2 No, that's a totally different meaning. That means "I don't even consider it eating unless I go absolutely ham". So, I do eat normally sometimes, but I occasionally gulp down food like a crazy person. 

Still no idea how it helps with my original question. `Hardly a lawyer unless took up the question` makes sense to you?

Comment: @Yeats You should go back and re-read my post. I did say that syntactically "unless" cannot replace "but". You're presenting an archaic use of a word and are trying to make sense out of it, although you apparently don't speak that "older English". And I've tried my best to help you understand it, albeit imperfectly. If it doesn't help you at all, that's unfortunate. But no need to get so aggressive.

Comment: @JK2 When have I gotten aggressive? Your post confused me and I aired that confusion. You said you used to believe that the `but` in the proverb meant `unless` but you never go on to say what it does mean. I don't need to know, because the proverb is extremely easy to understand, but still. I cannot fit `unless` in my sentences at all. It just doesn't make sense. It's not the correct answer.

Comment: @Yeats Fine. Just downvote the answer and move on. Somebody else will help you...or not.

Comment: @JK2 You should have stated in your answer that you don't accept any questions and that your words are final as is and cannot be elaborated on.

Comment: @Yeats Where are your manners?? Oh, BTW, here are quite a number of examples of that "older English" having the unlikely expression "unless took" (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unless+took%22&rlz=1C1NHXL_koKR936KR936&biw=1280&bih=609&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvL1s1KlfViAznwWJmF2yo-1jeffJw%3A1639881782344&ei=Npy-YZ6MDZutoATH2IzABQ&ved=0ahUKEwie_-jY6-70AhWbFogKHUcsA1gQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22unless+took%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ2ghYoQpgmQxoAHAAeACAAWOIAYEDkgEBNJgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books).

Comment: @JK2 What's wrong with my manners? I tried to ask questions of you but you only got defensive and refused to answer them.

Comment: @JK2 If you click on the results, you'd see that all of those are mistakes. The `unless` sits next to `took` in a two-column page, making the parser believe they are part of the same sentence. Even if it was correct, it doesn't help me. I've never asked for `unless took`.