# The meaning of “but” in “never a woman but...”?

Tags: meaning, grammar

What’s the meaning of the second “but” in the following quote?

> Grammar! — what was that but the art of arranging words? — and he never knew a woman **but** could do that fast enough.
>
> From *My French Master*, David Moynihan

Does it mean “he never knew a woman, but he could arrange arrange word fast enough”?

Comment: I don't know who David Moynihan is. This is by Dickens, isn't it? Published in *Household Words* in December 1853.

Comment: Please **do not answer in comments.** If you have an answer, write an answer. It can even be a germ of an answer, but it must not be in comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to find a grammar rule that explains heavy use of ‘but’ instead of ‘that doesn’t’ in older English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/580080/trying-to-find-a-grammar-rule-that-explains-heavy-use-of-but-instead-of-that) ('The "nobbut" construction': J Lawler.) 'There was hardly a lawyer of repute but took up the question, and had an opinion as to Lizzie’s right to the necklace. ― Anthony Trollope' / 'It never rains but [what] it pours.'

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I believe it does! Thank you so much!